# Does reading the Quran remove sins?

Tags: quran, sin, deeds, reward

I watched a video where the man said that each letter of the Quran is 10 rewards which would equal approximately 33 million rewards if you complete/khatam the Quran (from mushaf). Then he said that the approximately 33 millions rewards remove approximately 33 million of your sins.

Is this true? Does reading the Quran remove sins and make rewards instead?

This is the video link: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8QrvW7R_qJM

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this has less to do with the Quran specifically, and more to do with good deeds in general.

The person probably meant to say that reciting the Quran gives a lot of good deeds, and getting a lot of good deeds is a good idea (in addition to the obvious reason) because good deeds erase bad deeds.

It is a well-known concept in Islam that good deeds erase bad deeds. To give one reference out of many for this, Allah says in the Quran:

> [...] Indeed, good deeds do away with misdeeds. [...] (11:114)